# MacOSX向けアプリで、QuickTimeの画面収録を検知する方法はありますか？

Tags: objective-c, macos

MacOSX向けのアプリで、QuickTimeの画面収録の開始・終了を検知する方法はありますでしょうか？

なにかしらのNotificationが通知されているなどであれば良いのですが、今の所探せておりません。

なお、iTunesStoreでレンタルしたコンテンツを、iTunes上で再生中にQuickTimeの画面収録を行うと、プレイヤーの再生画面がグレーにマスクがかかります。

ですので、なにか方法はあるのかな、と思っているのですが、いかがでしょうか。

ご存知の方がおりましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

iTunesと同じ方法で検知を行うのは難しいと思います。

iTunesは画面収録そのものではなく、再生中のディスプレイで[HDCP](http://e-words.jp/w/HDCP.html)が有効かどうかを検知している可能性が高いです。HDCPに対応していないディスプレイで再生したり、画面収録によって一時的にHDCPが無効になるとiTunesは再生を停止します。

しかし、HDCPが有効かどうかを調べるAPIは公開されていません。

参考: [Mac OS X public APIs for checking/requiring HDCP/DPCP protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654083/mac-os-x-public-apis-for-checking-requiring-hdcp-dpcp-protection?rq=1)